# How to group only by joined table column with Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I have one join table:

```
table1_id|table2_id
1|1
1|2
2|1
2|2
3|1
```

I need to select rows grouped by table2. But I need special grouping. In result row I want to see the following:

```
table1.id|grouped
1,2|1,2
3|1
```

I tried different ways.

- Select from table1 and group by table2.id. Fail - MySql required query to be grouped my primary table as well.
- Select from table2 and group by table1.id and table2.id . Fail - it selects rows from table2 separately, I want them to be concatenated as I shown in the example.
- Select from table1 and group by `group_concat(table2.id)`. But MySql does not allow to group by aggregated functions.

My example query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/934b64/4. I need almost the same, but so that it will one row with values:

```
1,2|1,2
3|1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in `SELECT` clause, not in `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT table1_id,GROUP_CONCAT(table2_id) as grouped
FROM table
GROUP BY table1_id;
```

See the result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a666a/3)

For your requirement, please try the below query:

```
select t1.id,t1.value, 
    group_concat(t2.id) as grouped_ids,
    group_concat(t2.value) as grouped_values
from table1 t1
join joined_table jt on jt.id1 = t1.id
join table2 t2 on t2.id = jt.id2
group by t1.id,t1.value
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb06da/2)

Comment: Strange. I see your query working. But it does not work with my. MySql says: "Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY." Actually, my table is join table. Does it matter?

Comment: @FreeLightman: You just need to mention all other fields in `GROUP BY` clause except `table2_id`. Can you provide the complete query?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up in the task. I updated the question and added real schema.

Comment: @FreeLightman, It is really difficult to give a solution without seeing some actual data. Anyway I have updated my answer with some sample values. Please give it a try.